# Showing runtime error on publishing on siteleaf

Tags: github, content-management-system, jekyll

Siteleaf continuously shows this error
`Error: expected "{". (RuntimeError)`
what is this and how can I solve this?

Trying to find a solution

Comment: Are you able to post whatever code you have on `Siteleaf`? It looks like the error is  saying something about your syntax being wrong. You'll have better luck getting an answer if you provide that information initially.

Comment: Thanks, @treckstar, It is fixed now 
there were some dependencies errors.